# Finding an Intersection of word with a data grid view

Tags: c#, view, datagridview, grid

I am trying to make a program like a crossword and have loaded files into a datagridview, to calculate the score i need to find letters that intersect like the letter 'a' below. The \ represents a null cell.

w \ \ \ \ \
a r t i s t
l  \  \  \ \  \
k  \ \ \ \ \

```
 for (int i =0; i<crosswordView.Rows.Count;i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j<crosswordView.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        //Check for an intersect 
        if(crossword[i,j].Value!=null)
        {
            if(crossword[i,j+1].Value!=null)
            {
               score++;
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

I am terrible with data grid things! I know this example doesn't work (just wanted to show how i have tried to traverse the grid). Is this the way or is there an easier to find an intersect?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but for what it's worth you can think like this:

you don't need to check intersection, instead check every cell value: if it's right give it a tag of 1 with `dgv.currentcell.tag = 1`

Then do like you mentioned but instead of checking for null values check for tag: if the tag is 1 then `score++`.

This will happen only once per cell so there will be no doubles